# Giving unique identifier to ambiguous parent level when reading XML data

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I have an XML document, which I've simplified for this question, in the following format:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
    <aggregateddata>
        <aggregateddata>
            <item value="abcdefg1" name="id"/>
            <item value="1" name="dataSet"/>
            <item value="Aggregates" name="dataSetLabel"/>
            <item value="Physical Flow" name="indicator"/>
            <item value="day" name="periodType"/>
            <item value="2021-10-16T06:00:00+02:00" name="periodFrom"/>
            <item value="2021-10-17T06:00:00+02:00" name="periodTo"/>
            <item value="BE" name="countryKey"/>
            <item value="L-Zone" name="bzShort"/>
        </aggregateddata>
        <aggregateddata>
            <item value="abcdefg2" name="id"/>
            <item value="1" name="dataSet"/>
            <item value="Aggregates" name="dataSetLabel"/>
            <item value="Physical Flow" name="indicator"/>
            <item value="day" name="periodType"/>
            <item value="2021-10-16T06:00:00+02:00" name="periodFrom"/>
            <item value="2021-10-17T06:00:00+02:00" name="periodTo"/>
            <item value="UK" name="countryKey"/>
            <item value="L-Zone" name="bzShort"/>
        </aggregateddata>
    </aggregateddata>
</xml>
```

I want to be able to read this, ideally having each group of values on its own row. Turning it into something more SQL server friendly Like this:

| id | dataSet | dataSetLabel | indicator | periodType | periodFrom | periodTo | countryKey | bzShort |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcdefg1 | 1 | Aggregates | Physical Flow | day | 2021-10-16T06:00:00+02:00 | 2021-10-17T06:00:00+02:00 | BE | L-Zone |
| abcdefg2 | 1 | Aggregates | Physical Flow | day | 2021-10-16T06:00:00+02:00 | 2021-10-17T06:00:00+02:00 | UK | L-Zone |

To do this, I though I could read the XML using the following:

```
select
    XMLDataNodes.x.value('@name', 'varchar(50)') as FieldName,
    XMLDataNodes.x.value('@value', 'varchar(500)') as FieldValue
from 
    @XmlFile.nodes ('/xml/aggregateddata/aggregateddata/item') as XMLDataNodes(x)
```

And then use some sort of dynamic pivot to then turn the results into what I need.

The problem though, is there is nothing I can 'group by' - basically no value on the parent note to put next to them. I have tried something like this https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/how-to-uniquely-number-parent-and-child-nodes-while-reading-an-xml-document, to add an identifier to each group, but it is incredibly slow on the actual full dataset:

```
select
    XMLDataNodes.x.value('@name', 'varchar(50)') as FieldName,
    XMLDataNodes.x.value('@value', 'varchar(500)') as FieldValue,
    XMLNodes.x.value('1+count(for $a in . return $a/../*[. << $a])','int') as parentID
from 
    @XmlFile.nodes ('/xml/aggregateddata/aggregateddata') as XMLNodes(x)
    cross apply XMLNodes.x.nodes('item') as XMLDataNodes(x)
```

Is there a way to either make the ID value much quicker, or pull the data out directly, without the need for this step (or the pivot afterwards)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

SQL Server's XQuery is very powerful.

The main idea is to use XPath with a predicate:

```
item[@name="..."]/@value
```

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
N'<xml>
    <aggregateddata>
        <aggregateddata>
            <item value="abcdefg1" name="id"/>
            <item value="1" name="dataSet"/>
            <item value="Aggregates" name="dataSetLabel"/>
            <item value="Physical Flow" name="indicator"/>
            <item value="day" name="periodType"/>
            <item value="2021-10-16T06:00:00+02:00" name="periodFrom"/>
            <item value="2021-10-17T06:00:00+02:00" name="periodTo"/>
            <item value="BE" name="countryKey"/>
            <item value="L-Zone" name="bzShort"/>
        </aggregateddata>
        <aggregateddata>
            <item value="abcdefg2" name="id"/>
            <item value="1" name="dataSet"/>
            <item value="Aggregates" name="dataSetLabel"/>
            <item value="Physical Flow" name="indicator"/>
            <item value="day" name="periodType"/>
            <item value="2021-10-16T06:00:00+02:00" name="periodFrom"/>
            <item value="2021-10-17T06:00:00+02:00" name="periodTo"/>
            <item value="UK" name="countryKey"/>
            <item value="L-Zone" name="bzShort"/>
        </aggregateddata>
    </aggregateddata>
</xml>';

SELECT c.value('(item[@name="id"]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as id
    , c.value('(item[@name="dataSet"]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(500)') as dataSet
    , c.value('(item[@name="dataSetLabel"]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(500)') as dataSetLabel
    , c.value('(item[@name="indicator"]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(500)') as indicator
    , c.value('(item[@name="periodType"]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(500)') as periodType
    , c.value('(item[@name="periodFrom"]/@value)[1]', 'datetimeoffset(0)') as periodFrom
    , c.value('(item[@name="periodTo"]/@value)[1]', 'datetimeoffset(0)') as periodTo
    , c.value('(item[@name="countryKey"]/@value)[1]', 'CHAR(2)') as countryKey
    , c.value('(item[@name="bzShort"]/@value)[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') as bzShort
FROM @xml.nodes('/xml/aggregateddata/aggregateddata') as t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----------+---------+--------------+---------------+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+------------+---------+
|    id    | dataSet | dataSetLabel |   indicator   | periodType |         periodFrom         |          periodTo          | countryKey | bzShort |
+----------+---------+--------------+---------------+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+------------+---------+
| abcdefg1 |       1 | Aggregates   | Physical Flow | day        | 2021-10-16 06:00:00 +02:00 | 2021-10-17 06:00:00 +02:00 | BE         | L-Zone  |
| abcdefg2 |       1 | Aggregates   | Physical Flow | day        | 2021-10-16 06:00:00 +02:00 | 2021-10-17 06:00:00 +02:00 | UK         | L-Zone  |
+----------+---------+--------------+---------------+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+------------+---------+
```

Comment: Ah - yes. That is exactly what I wanted to know how to do. `item[@name="..."]/@value` is perfect for what I want here. Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't `(item/@value)[1]` be `(item[@name="id"]/@value)[1]`

Comment: Charlie, eagle eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might help (and should be faster than a dynamic XQuery, at least):

```
select 
    XmlDataNodes.x.value('(item[@name="id"]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(500)') as Id,
    Items.*
from 
    @XmlFile.nodes ('/xml/aggregateddata/aggregateddata') as XMLDataNodes(x)
    cross apply (
       select
         ItemNodes.x.value('@name', 'varchar(50)') as FieldName,
         ItemNodes.x.value('@value', 'varchar(500)') as FieldValue
       from XMLDataNodes.x.nodes('item') ItemNodes(x)
    ) Items
```

Result:

| Id | FieldName | FieldValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abcdefg1 | id | abcdefg1 |
| abcdefg1 | dataSet | 1 |
| abcdefg1 | dataSetLabel | Aggregates |
| abcdefg1 | indicator | Physical Flow |
| ... | ... | ... |

Comment: Thank you - yes, that is a great way to achieve what I want in regards to the unique identifier. I  feel @Yitzhak Khabinsky's answer better achieves my main need though. Thanks for you suggestion!